# Rate distortion function with infinite distortion

Tags: probability, optimization, coding-theory, information-theory, entropy

I am working through the problems in Elements of Information Theory by Cover and Thomas and have come across the following problem I couldn't answer.

The problem is to find the rate distortion function $R(D) = \min_{p(\hat x | x)} I(X;\hat X)$ for $X$ ~ Bernoulli$(\frac{1}{2})$ and distortion $d(x, \hat x)$ defined as

\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=\hat x$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=1$ and $\hat x=0$} \\
\infty, & \text{if $x=0$ and $\hat x=1$}
\end{cases}

The solution I have defines $p(x,\hat x)$ as:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
        D & \frac{1}{2}-D \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot figure out how this distribution was derived.  I understand that $d(0,1)=\infty$ implies that $p(0,1)=0$, assuming that $D$ is finite.  But I cannot derive the other three entries...  Can someone offer a hint?

Answer (score 3):

Apologies in advance for not being able to format this properly.

The definition of D is the expectation value, E, of the distortion measure.  E[d(x, x^)] = p(1|0) * 1 = p(1|0)= D.  Now, because X is Bernoulli with probability 1/2, we have that p(0) = 1/2 = p(0|0) + p(0|1)  = p(0|0).  Finally p(1) = 1/2 = p(1|0) + p(1|1) = D + p(1|1), so p(1|1) = 1/2 - D.

This should take care of all the entries.